# Include error using PocketSphinx 5.0.2 library visual studio code cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, include, pocketsphinx

I installed cmake tools from visual studio extensions, but I don't know how to install PocketSphinx 5.0.2 library into my project? Could you help? Include error using PocketSphinx 5.0.2 library visual studio code cmake.I installed cmake tools from visual studio code extensions. How can I add the library?
I was expecting it to work but it didn't work